# Laravel Display Product name instead of ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to display the Product name instead of just the Item id.

My code:

```
{{$fd->purchase->product_id}}
```

How can I change this? Because in my Feedback DB Table are only the Product ID?

How can I do this with the `Laravel Database: Query Builder`?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your full query code under controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a relationship:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

And use it:

```
{{ $fd->purchase->product->name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of define relationship between Purchase and Product

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Product);
}
```

And use its in view :

```
{{ $fd->purchase->product->product_name }}
```